# How to handle Application_AcquireRequestState, Session_Start and Session_End in ASP.NET 4.5 using OWIN?

Tags: asp.net, owin

We use ASP.NET 4.5 (VS 2013) and want to replace Global.asax.cs with new Startup.cs file, which comes from OWIN specification.

We need to replace Application_AcquireRequestState, Session_Start and Session_End handlers with something in Startup.cs file. It looks as following in Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void (Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SessionCounter.AddSessionPage(Context);
}

protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoginLog.RegisterLogOff(Context);
    SessionCounter.AbandonSession(Context);
}
```

How can we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OWIN has no definition for session and cannot fully replace the Global.asax.cs file.

Try ASP.NET 5, it moves everything from Global.asax.cs to Startup.cs. https://github.com/aspnet/home